# Unable to load GUI in ubuntu server 15.10

Tags: server, gnome

I have installed ubuntu server 15.10 64 bit in oracle VM. To start the GUI i have entered this command `sudo apt-get install xorg gnome-core gnome-system-tools gnome-app-install`. And downloaded and installed the packages. After that I type startx and getting the errors saying

```
xinit:connection to X server lost
waiting for X server to shut down setting MTRR (base = 0xe0000000, size=0x00c00000,type=1) No such device (19)
(II) Server trminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Any help ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go - a simple one would be to just install the full blown desktop environment via

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

This keeps your work simple, but comes with a big amount of additional packages you might not need in a classical server environment (where even GUIs are not used in the first place)

Additional informations about Server & GUI can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI).

In case you want to debug the above,  start with the log